# `lc_time_names` has no effect

Tags: mysql, my.ini

I have a Windows MySQL server running (5.6), and in the `my.ini` file I have the following directive under [mysqld]:

```
lc_time_names = 'fr_FR';
```

But it has ZERO effect. When I start up the server, all time names are still in English. If I then launch Workbench and issue the following command:

```
SET GLOBAL lc_time_names = 'fr_FR';
```

it works and the times are changed. Is there something different I need to do in `my.ini`?

UPDATE (VERY IMPORTANT):
in addition to needing to put this value in the correct ini file, you also need to NOT ADD QUOTES!! I broke my server with the above, and it took me forever to figure out I needed to change the line to

```
lc_time_names = fr_FR
```

WITHOUT THE QUOTES, or your MySQL server will not start up! Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: are you sure you are modifying right `my.ini`?

Comment: well, in services it states the location as:  --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" and so that is the file I am editing.

Comment: UGH, I think you are right. The program is installed in Program Files, but for some reason the installer was pointing to the INVISIBLE ProgramData folder by default. I have now found that file and changed it, let's see at next startup if that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass the third parameter as a local value. ^^

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2023-06-15", '%W %d %M %Y','it_IT') as date;

output: giovedì 15 giugno 2023

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2023-06-15", '%W %d %M %Y','fr_FR') as date;

output  : jeudi 15 juin 2023

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2023-06-15", '%W %d %M %Y','ja_JP') as date;

output : 木曜日 15 6月 2023

for more information, here  [MySQL Server Locale Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html)